# Scaling problem

Tags: transforms

I am a very newbie to Blender. Trying to get used to modelling now.

I selected the faces on both sides on this object with shift+click, and scaled down by Y axis by S+Y, but the result is not what I wanted.
I want the two edges pointed by the arrows to be scaled down too.

Proportion editing does the similar thing, but since the whole object around the circle get scaled down as well, this is not what I need.

I'd appreciate if you know some solution. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: It looks as if you may inadvertantly have duplicate overlapping faces there. Hit 'A' in Edit mode to select the whole object then 'M' > Merge by Distance and watch the centre of the bottom status bar to see if any vertices have been removed. Then try scaling again.

Comment: @JohnEason It worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: Good! It's possible that you selected E (Extrude) for that face (or even the whole object) at some stage but then cancelled it with Esc without moving anything. That will still leave a duplicate copy in place even if you thought you'd cancelled it and can't see it.